# Apache Beam sliding windows

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-beam

Let's suppose that I have an 2 hours window that starts every 1 minute.
Next step would be to apply GroupBy transform.

Is it  holding copies of overlapping data for each window separately in memory? Or Apache Beam has a logic to know that record A belongs to multiple windows?

I would be grateful for explaining this. Could not really find relevant information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an implementation detail that should not be observable (or observed) by pipeline authors. Beam/runner can potentially decide to fuse multiple transforms and keep and reuse the elements in memory. Or not.

I don't know whether this specific topic is covered, but there are few words about immutability of the elements at the end of [`ParDo` section in the programming guide](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#pardo). And overall description of Beam execution model is [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/execution-model/).